# Custom presence channel for larger (more than 100 users) audience with pusher

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pusher, pusher-js

I'm building an event page where every user has it's chat. The user can only chat with a moderator (which has its own separate dashboard). So it's a one on one communication. The user on the frontend doesn't need any information who else is online but the moderator has to be able to see how many people are online and if the users are online based on their user_id.

I've found this link to customize a 'presence' channel https://support.pusher.com/hc/en-us/articles/360019620253-How-can-I-implement-large-presence-channels-on-Channels- but i'm not sure where to start.

As i see it - every user which is online on the event page has to subscribe to a 'online-users' channel.

In the moderator dashboard i should be able to query the 'online-users' channel distinct subscribed count and to get all user_ids. This should be then scalable to > 100 users right?

Those 'pusher:member_added' events are for presence- channels only right?

```
GET /apps/[app_id]/channels/[channel_name]/users
```

Apparently there is also this call but as stated only available for presence channels..?

Comment: You could check [Pusher DOC](https://pusher.com/docs/channels/using_channels/presence-channels) based on `keywords` from [BUILDING A LARGER PRESENCE IMPLEMENTATION - steps](https://support.pusher.com/hc/en-us/articles/360019620253-How-can-I-implement-large-presence-channels-on-Channels-). Add you may try to get help by requesting a [Pusher ticket](https://support.pusher.com/hc/en-us/requests/new), as they are the experts about using pusher.